# What is an Integer?

Tags: java

An integer programming problem is a mathematical optimization or feasibility program in which some or all of the variables are restricted to be integers.

Comment: It looks like the error message you pasted got truncated. Can you paste the full compiler output?

Comment: I updated the post with the full compiler error.

Comment: Please add enough code so that we can tell what `E` is in each context. (Like maybe a `template<something> class something {`...`};`?)

Comment: E type in ABag is `KVpair<std::string,int>`, E type in Dictionary is `int`. The compiler informs you of it, can't convert `int` to `KVpair<std::string,int>`

Comment: A [mcve] is helpful, because what you have here is too piecemeal and convoluted, and if I put in the missing pieces to get it to compile there is a good chance I'll not put in the bug that you are experiencing.

Comment: @tellemiller The error message you have shown does not match the code you have shown.  The template parameters of `BDictionary` and thus of `KVpair` in the error message are reversed.

Comment: You misunderstand the type system. `E& returnValue` means that `returnValue` must be initialized by an lvalue expression, and it will name the same object as that expression did. Once it has been initialized, it is an expression of type `E`  (not `E&`). Expressions never have reference type.

Comment: You removed the code. The code you had seemed to be in c++ rather than Java. Also, this invalidated one or more of the answers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `myIntStrDict` variable is declared as `BDictionary<int, std::string>`. `BDictionary`'s `Key` is `int` and `E` is `std::string`.

When you call `myIntStrDict.removeAny(strData)`, the `BDictionary::removeAny()` method takes an `E&` aka `std::string&` as input, and `strData` is a `std::string`, so all is OK.

Inside of `BDictionary`, its `dictionary` member is declared as `ABag<KVpair<Key, E>>*`. `ABag`'s `E` is `KVpair<Key, E>`.

The `ABag::removeTop()` method takes an `E&` aka `KVpair<Key, E>&` as input, not a `std::string&` like you are expecting.

So, when you are calling `dictionary->removeTop(returnValue)`, you are passing a `std::string` where a `KVpair` is expected, and that is why the compiler fails.

To do what you are attempting, you need to fix the implementation of your `BDictionary::removeAny()` method to accept a `KVpair`, and the nyou can extract the `std::string` for that, eg:

```
//BDictionary.h
template <typename Key, typename E>
class BDictionary : public Dictionary<Key, E> {

    ABag<KVpair<Key, E>>* dictionary;   //Dictionary object

    bool removeAny(E& returnValue) {     //The Dictionary method that accepts an E& value       
        KVpair<Key, E> pair;
        bool res = dictionary->removeTop(pair);
        if (res) returnValue = pair.second; // or however KVpair refers to its 2nd element
        return res;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In `BDictionary<E>::removeAny`, the call to `ABag<KVPair<Key, E>>::removeTop` wants to "return" a `KVPair<Key, E>`. But `removeAny` is only equipped to "return" an `E`. You cannot pass the `E &returnValue` argument of `removeAny` on to `removeTop`, since `removeTop` will want to return the whole pair and not just the value, but only the value will "fit" in the `E&`.

Without going into and modifying the internals of `ABag`, I think the best you can do is create a temporary `KVPair<Key, E>` "destination" in `removeAny` to hold the value coming from `removeTop`, and then pass along just the value part of that pair. This is ugly, but it works:

```
bool removeAny(E &returnValue) {
    KVPair<Key, E> dest;
    bool removed = dictionary->removeTop(dest);
    if(removed) returnValue = std::move(dest.value); // or however you get the value out
    return removed;
}
```

Alternately, modify the signature of `removeAny` so that it, too, returns the entire pair.

```
bool removeAny(KVPair<Key, E> &dest) {
    return dictionary->removeTop(dest);
}
```

This would require modifying your calling code (in `bagtestmain.cpp`).